# How does read-line work in Lisp when reaching eof?

Tags: file-io, lisp, common-lisp

Context:
I have a text file called `fr.txt` with 3 columns of text in it:

```
65  A   #\A
97  a   #\a
192     À   #\latin_capital_letter_a_with_grave
224     à   #\latin_small_letter_a_with_grave
etc...
```

I want to create a function to read the first (and eventually the third one too) column and write it into another text file called `alphabet_code.txt`.

So far I have this function:

```
(defun alphabets()
   (setq source (open "fr.txt" :direction :input :if-does-not-exist :error))
   (setq code (open "alphabet_code.txt" :direction :output :if-does-not-exist :create :if-exists :supersede))
   (loop
      (setq ligne (read-line source nil nil))
      (cond
         ((equal ligne nil) (return))
         (t (print (read-from-string ligne) code))
      )
   )
   (close code)
   (close source)
)
```

My problems:

1. I don't really  understand how the parameters of read-line function. I have read [this doc](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_lin.htm), but it's still very obscure to me. If someone would have very simple examples, that would help.
2. With the current code, I get this error: `*** - read: input stream #<input string-input-stream> has reached its end`  even if I change the `nil nil` in `(read-line source nil nil)` to other values.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You CAN'T create local variables with SETQ. Where did you get this use of SETQ from?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: why is that? That's what my professor uses in the course.

Comment: Because SETQ is defined to set existing variables. It does not introduce new variables, especially not local variables. Local variables are introduced for example by LET and LET*. If your professor is using SETQ like in your example, you might inform him/her with great care, that this is wrong. If he/she has questions they are welcome to Stackoverflow and we will explain it...

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I think this pervasive attempted use of assignment operators for binding is likely Python braindamage.  The confusion of assignment and binding might be Python's single worst feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Your questions

### `read-line` optional arguments

[`read-line`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_lin.htm) accepts 3 optional arguments:

1. `eof-error-p`: what to do on EOF (default: error)
2. `eof-value`: what to return instead of the error when you see EOF
3. `recursive-p`: are you calling it from your [`print-object`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_pr_obj.htm) method (forget about this for now)

E.g., when the `stream` is at EOF,

- `(read-line stream)` will signal the [`end-of-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/e_end_of.htm) error
- `(read-line stream nil)` will return `nil`
- `(read-line stream nil 42)` will return `42`.

Note that `(read-line stream nil)` is the same as `(read-line stream nil nil)` but people usually still pass the second optional argument explicitly.
`eof-value` of `nil` is fine for `read-line` because `nil` is not a string and `read-line` only returns strings.

Note also that in case of [`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) the second optional argument is, traditionally, the `stream` itself: `(read stream nil stream)`. It's quite convenient.

### Error

You are getting the error from [`read-from-string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_fro.htm), not [`read-line`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_lin.htm), because, apparently, you have an empty line in your file.

I know that because the error mentions [`string-input-stream`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_stg_st.htm), not [`file-stream`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_file_s.htm).

## Your code

Your code is correct functionally, but very wrong stylistically.

1. You should use [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm) whenever possible.
2. You should not use [`print`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) in code, it's a weird legacy function mostly for interactive use.
3. You can't create local variables with [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm) - use [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) or other equivalent forms (in this case, you never need `let`! :-)

Here is how I would re-write your function:

```
(defun alphabets (input-file output-file)
  (with-open-stream (source input-file)
    (with-open-stream (code output-file :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
      (loop for line = (read-line source nil nil)
          as num = (parse-integer line :junk-allowed t)
        while line do
          (when num
            (write num :stream code)
            (write-char #\Newline code))))))
(alphabets "fr.txt" "alphabet_code.txt")
```

See the docs:

1. [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm): [`for/as`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abad.htm), [`while`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ad.htm), [`do`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ae.htm)
2. [`write`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm), [`write-char`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_cha.htm)
3. [`parse-integer`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_parse_.htm)

Alternatively, instead of `(when num ...)` I could have use the corresponding [`loop` conditional](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_af.htm).

Also, instead of `write`+`write-char` I could have written `(format code "~D~%" num)`.

Note that I do *not* pass those of your `with-open-stream` arguments that are identical to the defaults.
The defaults are set in stone, and the less code you have to write and your user has to read, the less is the chance of an error.